# How to get DOM elements added dynamically

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, scrollspy

I am using Anchorjs with Bootstrap scrollspy (or at least trying to!).

AnchorJS adds id to each element on `DOMContentLoaded`:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function (event) {
    const anchors = new AnchorJS();
    anchors.add('.post h2:not(:empty), .post h3:not(:empty), .post'
        + ' h4:not(:empty), .post h5:not(:empty), .post h6:not(:empty),'
        + ' .post p:not(:empty)');
    anchors.options = {icon: '#'};

});
```

ScrollSpy is initiated after `complete` `readystatechange`:

```
document.addEventListener('readystatechange', event => {

    if (event.target.readyState === "complete") {
        const scrollSpyContentEl = document.getElementById('body')

        const scrollSpy = bootstrap.ScrollSpy.getOrCreateInstance(scrollSpyContentEl, {
            target: '#anchor-list',
            offset: 36,
        }) // Returns a Bootstrap scrollspy instance
    }
});
```

However, I still get an a `Uncaught DOMException`:

> Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '#example-anchor' is not a valid selector.

This is presumably because `document.getElementById('body')` does not include the IDs set by AnchorJS.

How can I fix this? `scrollspy.refresh()` makes no difference.